# eclipse + maven + tomcat7 + wtp, can't start project when checked "Serve modules without publishing"

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7, eclipse-wtp

My project on github: https://github.com/henryyan/kft-activiti-demo

Normally unchecked "Serve modules without publishing", the project can be started. After checked occurred error (Tomcat6 are ok!!!):

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/henryyan/work/projects/activiti/kft-activiti-demo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml (No such file or directory)

why find file "applicationContext.xml" from "**src**", it it should be target/classes.

Full log: https://gist.github.com/4407208

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your resources as web resources in the maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <webResources>
         <resource>                      
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </resource>
      </webResources>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you using m2e? Try to remove your .settings folder and do 'Update project' in the Maven menu.

Comment: Can you check something else? Open .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component and check if it has a line <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>

Comment: yes, <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="src/main/resources"/> in .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component